# tensorflow: how to do numpy-like range with a tensor

Tags: tensorflow

```
def inference(arg1, arg2):
     #something to do
     for x in np.range(arg2):
          #to do
```

in the above code, I define a model, and want to range in the arg2, like numpy:
`for i in numpy.range(arg2)`, the problem is that arg2 is a tensor, maybe a from a `tf.placeholder()`, but how??

## Edit：

in fact, my code like this:

```
def inference(arg1, arg2):
   #to do

   return loss

loss = inference(arg1, arg2)
#do something about tf.optimizer 

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run()
```

so my first question is in the function `inference()` I can define a session, and call session.run() again?

second, I do this, but it turns out that:

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Cannot assign a device to node 'tower_3/train/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue': Could not satisfy explicit device specification '/device:GPU:3' because no supported kernel for GPU devices is available.
Colocation Debug Info:
Colocation group had the following types and devices: 
QueueEnqueue: CPU 
QueueSize: CPU 
QueueClose: CPU 
QueueDequeueMany: CPU 
RandomShuffleQueue: CPU 
     [[Node: tower_3/train/shuffle_batch/random_shuffle_queue = RandomShuffleQueue[capacity=3, component_types=[DT_INT64, DT_INT64, DT_INT64], container="", min_after_dequeue=0, seed=0, seed2=0, shapes=[[260], [], []], shared_name="", _device="/device:GPU:3"]()]]`

same problem on the cpu

so I do not know, in tensorflow many functions like tf.range() just accept python int, but when I have a tensor, what i can do? It makes me crazy

## Edit again

for example, the [mnist](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist.py) in the tutorials, the model is defined in the function `inference()` that uses a `tf.placeholder()`, in the funciont `run_training()` of fully_connected_feed.py, this feed it images and labels, then `sess.run()`, so in function `inference()`, if you want to get the tensor `images` with this code:

```
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(images)
```

it will turn out:

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [100,784]
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[100,784], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
     [[Node: Placeholder/_2 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_5_Placeholder", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]`

it looks like in that moment, there is no image has been feed to the tensor `images`

## Edit again again

I am doing something about nlp, the arg1 maybe be the sentence with diffrent length, so I have make a max_len, while record the real length in arg2

it's encoder and decoder program using lstm, in phase of decoder, I want to add a attention model, so I must know the length of sentence to compute the importance of every word in the sentence, but the length is a tensor, I can not do something like:

```
for x in len:
   #do something
```

Comment: you need to evaluate the `arg2` first using `session.run`. That gives you numpy array back

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov it does not work

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do with this loop? You can easily create `tf.range(arg2)`, or maybe use `tf.while()` loop. It depends on what you try to do inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You can run an evaluation on the tensor to get its value:

```
def inference(arg1, arg2):
    with sess.as_default():
        #something to do
        for x in np.range(arg2.eval()):
            #to do
```

or:

```
def inference(arg1, arg2):
    #something to do
    for x in np.range(sess.run(arg2)):
        #to do
```